# How do i remove 'onClick' attribute from a ReactJS Component?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, reactjs, babeljs

I'm just getting started with `NodeJS` and `ReactJS`. I'm not quite clear about some stuff.

```
render( ) {
return (
  <div>
    <img src={this.props.pic}
         onclick={this.props.cb()}
         class="af1" />
  </div>
 );
}
```

above is my render method for `App` Component. I want to remove `onClick` attribute after clicking on the image for the first time and disable image(`not able to click again`) for 10 seconds or so (please suggest me if there's any better way to disable clicking on image temporarily).
Will this be a good solution?

and why cant i see `onclick` attrib in chrome's developer console?
I really have started to like learning this stuff, i'm getting lost somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class App extend React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.onImageClick = this.onImageClick.bind(this);
        this.timeDelay= this.timeDelay.bind(this);
    }

    onImageClick(...args){
        // do something
    }

    timeDelay(func, delay){
        var isCalled = false;
        return (args)=>{
           if (!isCalled){
               isCalled = true;
               func(event);
               setTimeout(()=>{
                  isCalled = false;
               }, delay)
           }
        }
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        this.onImageClickWithTimeDelay = this.timeDelay(this.onImageClick, 10000);
    }

    render(){
        return <div>
            <img src={this.props.pic} onClick={ this.onImageClickWithTimeDelay }/>
        </div>
    }
}
```

I hope this is useful for you.

Comment: Can you please briefly explain? I didn't quite understand what's happening in timeDelay method and constructor.

Comment: $('#btndisable').prop('disabled', true);
        setTimeout(()=>{
          $('#btndisable').prop('disabled', false);
        },10000)_how about if i use this if there's only button_? @Vasi

Comment: The timeDelay method has two arguments. The func means your function and delay means how long block your function call. 

If you call timeDelay function with correct arguments it returns a function.
You put this function where you want.
The return function has a check ( isCalled ), the check is decide will call your function or not. Your delay times later the check is toggled. So you call your function after delay time finished, the function is will call.

Comment: If your element is a button you can use button disabled method. Otherwise you have use my method.

Comment: When I click on image for second time. Won't `isCalled` will be again set to false? And this loop happens everytime I click on it?

Comment: Yeah, every time click on image just check this time will call your function or not. It's works or not?

Comment: Thanks its working. can you please explain me `return (...args)` this part. where's `...args` coming from?

Comment: Your function have any arguments?

Comment: No im not passing any args when i click on image

Comment: If you want to pass argument to your function my the my returns function get all arguments as args then pass args to your function. After your function get your arguments then use it.

Comment: It's okay buddy. You carry on.